# How to get marketing conversion data by ad, adset, and campaign via Facebook's API (Fivetran custom report)

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api, dbt, fivetran

Running into an issue with the marketing API. I'm using Fivetran to pull custom reports, specifically performance at the ad level (spend, reach, imps, clicks, conversions, etc.) by adset and campaign.

This is a picture of the customer report setup in Fivetran: https://gyazo.com/9c9c850e1f738f6cf59f33f13f1985e3

From this report, Facebook exports 4 separate tables into Snowflake: https://gyazo.com/097de3b20f7561db6f85fafe7b4a10bb

This is the main table with most of the KPIs broken out by ad, adset, and campaign: https://gyazo.com/074481699cf5fed4f0fb951424111d59

However, conversions sit in a separate table: https://gyazo.com/8d6da656a72f7e3025950c4bdc533478

My expectation is the conversion table would also include IDs for adset and campaign so I could join the two tables in dbt, however, the conversions table only has ad_id and date, which would be inaccurate.

Am I missing a configuration in Fivetran or is this a limitation on the Facebook side?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?